# phpunit merge two or more clover.xml reports

Tags: php, phpunit, code-coverage, clover

I have several clover.xml reports of different extensions of a projects. I want to combine them into one clover.xml and then create it into a clover html. But i see no way with the phpunit classes `PHP_CodeCoverage`, `PHP_CodeCoverage_Report_HTML`, `PHP_CodeCoverage_Report_Clover`.

None of these classes accept an existing clover.xml. I thought I might be able to work with the methods append and merge of `PHP_CodeCoverage`. But that does not accept files.

Comment: Same problem here. It's a matrix build. Each clover.xml has certain skips. While the merged clover.xml shouldn't have them. PHPUnit does not provide a coverage merging util.

Comment: I guess it cannot be done. As PHPUnit is using xdebug to find out which lines have been called and which hasn't. To just merge the line coverage seems to be possible. But if you look into the xml file, you'll see that there are other metrics, like statement coverage.
For that you need to tokenize the source to decide if a statement (function) has been fully covered or not.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running jenkins or similar include a php script in your Ant build file to merge the files using [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php)

An example is here 
http://kuttler.eu/post/merging-and-splitting-xml-files-with-simplexml/

Then in your post build actions jenkins will use the clover.xml to generate your code coverage

[image]

Comment: But how exactly to merge different coverage XML? I mean based on which XML node? My XML have (roughly) the following structure:
<coverage ...>
 <project ...>
  <file ...>
   <class ...> ... </class>
   <line .../>
   <line .../>
   ... </file></project></coverage>

Comment: Sorry, but I couldn't find a way to format/structure the XML in the comments section.

Comment: Here's an example of how to merge 2 xml reports. Though this is for merging phpcs.xml files the concept is the same.http://beagile.biz/merge-2-php-code-sniffer-clover-xml-reports/

Answer (score 0):

As jkrnak commented above you cannot simply merge the XML files as there are computed values such as lines covered etc.. that are computed at output time. You need to "merge" while still working with native PHP code. In my case I wanted to capture the coverage of a series of web service calls executed by newman. To do this I set a flag at the beginning of execution which persists across invocations (using a cache) and then also save the PHP_CodeCoverage object in the cache as well. My implementation (in Laravel) looks something like this:

```
if ( isset($_GET['initCoverage']) )
{
    Cache::put( 'recordCoverage', true, 1440 );
}

if ( Cache::has('recordCoverage') )
{
    if ( Cache::has('coverage') )
    {
        $coverage = Cache::get('coverage');
    }
    else
    {
        $filter = new PHP_CodeCoverage_Filter;
        $filter->addDirectoryToBlacklist( base_path() . '/vendor' );

        $coverage = new PHP_CodeCoverage( null, $filter );
    }

    $coverage->start( Request::method() . " " . Request::path() );

    if ( isset($_GET['dumpCoverage']) )
    {
        if ( Cache::has('coverage') ) 
        {
            // Prevent timeout as writing coverage reports takes a long time
            set_time_limit( 0 );

            $coverage = Cache::get( 'coverage' );
            $writer = new PHP_CodeCoverage_Report_Clover;
            $writer->process($coverage, 'results/coverage/clover.xml');
        }

        Cache::forget('recordCoverage');
        Cache::forget('coverage');
    }
    else
    {
        register_shutdown_function( function($coverage) 
        {
            $coverage->stop();

            Cache::put( 'coverage', $coverage, 1440);
        }, $coverage);
    }
}
```

This captures the series of tests in a single coverage object which is then output when I make a call with the "dumpCoverage" flag.

Answer (score 0):

Years later this issue is still partly unsolved. There is a [project by SB](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpcov#merging-exported-php_codecoverage-objects-stored-in-cov-files) that can merge clover files, but it requires php 5.6.

None of the answers above work sufficiently well. [Here is a gist](https://gist.github.com/YarekTyshchenko/4092308fc5fa87ad1791) of a merge thrown together. Constructive critisism welcome.

Usage:

```
php clover-merge.php -o merged.xml -f clover-phpunit.xml -f clover-phpspec.xml
```

Posting it here for posterity too:

```
<?php
$options = getopt("f:o:");
if (! isset($options['f'])) {
    echo "Files have to be specified with -f\n";
    exit(1);
}
if (! isset($options['o'])) {
    echo "Output has to be specified with -o\n";
    exit(1);
}

$files = $options['f'];
if (! is_array($files)) {
    $files = array($files);
}
$output = $options['o'];

$buffer = '';
foreach ($files as $file) {
    if (! file_exists($file)) {
        echo "File '$file' doesn't exist\n";
        exit(2);
    }
    $report = simplexml_load_file($file);
    $buffer .= $report->project->asXML();
}

$fh = fopen($output ,'w');
if (! $fh) {
    echo "Cannot open '$output' for writing\n";
    exit(2);
}
fwrite($fh, sprintf('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><coverage>%s</coverage>', $buffer));
fclose($fh);
```